Trabajando con RDLC y me da un error de conexion a Base de datos
estoy trabajando en C# con SQL Server y estoy armando un informe con MS RDLC pero me da un error de conexión a la base de datos y me salta el siguiente error.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'La conexión con el servidor se ha establecido correctamente, pero se ha producido un error durante el proceso de inicio de sesión. (provider: Proveedor de SSL, error: 0 - La cadena de certificación fue emitida por una entidad en la que no se confía.)'

Toda la conexiones debería estar lista, ya que utilizo un StringConection y me trae los datos de la base de datos en buena condiciones hice mi DataStore, realice igualmente la conexión y la probé, pero aun así me da este error
Esta es la conexión que ocupo para conectarme a la base de datos
 Conex = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source="+nom_server()+ "\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=sistemaPresupuesto;Integrated Security=True; Encrypt = False");

Este es la que ocupo para el DataSet

Que podría estar malo, para que me salte ese error.
Gracias a todos

En la imagen se ve que tienes el parámetro Trust server certificate en falso, por lo que tu aplicación requiere que el servidor utilice un certificado emitido por una autoridad de confianza, pero al momento de conectarse no lo encuentra.

Es lo que dice, con toda claridad el mensaje de error, en esta parte:
La cadena de certificación fue emitida por una entidad en la que no se confía.

Hay dos posibles soluciones, la que uses depende de los requisitos de tu aplicación y del nivel de cumplimiento que debas tener en temas de seguridad.
Permitir certificados auto-firmados
Para ello, cambia el valor del parámetro Trust server certificate a True al configurar la conexión. Al conectarse, el cliente confiará en el certificado del servidor, es decir, aceptará el certificado auto-firmado que el servidor le presenta y procederá a la conexión sin problemas.
Proveer un certificado de una autoridad de confianza
La explicación de esto rebasa el alcance de esta respuesta, si tienes un administrador de red o un administrador de base de datos, pídele que configure un certificado emitido por una autoridad de confianza en el servidor de base de datos. Estos certificados se compran en Internet.
Si tienes que hacerlo tu solo, puedes iniciar leyendo la documentación: Administración de certificados (Administrador de configuración de SQL Server). Allí encontrarás enlaces y la información necesaria para realizar este proceso con éxito.
Si enfrentas nuevos retos, siempre puedes volver acá y publicar una nueva pregunta con el tema que te esté bloqueando.

Gracias por tu ayuda

Un gusto @Juan, veo que estás en Puerto Montt, hace menos de dos semanas estuve en Valdivia, muy cerca de allí, para lo habitual para mi, jeje. Un saludo.

Un Gusto si vivo en Puerto Montt hace mas de 15 años pero soy de Iquique., jajjaa
